# Blank Page after granting OAuth2 permission in BigQuery GAE Sample

Tags: google-app-engine, google-bigquery

I've been trying to play with the BigQuery GAE sample. 
All works well until after I've granted the app permission to access the BigQuery API, at the consent page. 
After that a blank page is displayed, with 'state' and 'code' parameters being part of the quesry string.

Everything gets stuck here, what must I do next?

Comment: just to be sure: can you give me the URL of where you found the BigQuery GAE sample?

Comment: Hi Fh. This is URL: https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery-tools/source/browse/#git%2Fsamples%2Fpython%2Fappengine-bq-join

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of doing the oauth2 dance, you could use the appengine.AppAssertionCredentials, to get a signed token from within the app:

```
import httplib2
from apiclient import discovery
from google.appengine.api import app_identity
from oauth2client import appengine
PROJECT_ID = app_identity.get_application_id()

query = {'query':'SELECT word,count(word) AS count FROM publicdata:samples.shakespeare GROUP BY word limit 3;'}

service = discovery.build(
    "bigquery", "v2", http=appengine.AppAssertionCredentials(
        scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery').authorize(
            httplib2.Http()))
jobRunner = service.jobs().query(projectId=PROJECT_ID, body=query)
print jobRunner.execute()
```

For this to work you need to add @developer.gserviceaccount.com to the team as a viewer on https://cloud.google.com/console.

Comment: Thanks for your response Fh. Does this mean there's something wrong with the sample as it is right now?

Comment: I haven't had time to review the sample, but I'd like to rewrite, with auth on the service account next time :)